# Как сделать кнопку на сайте изначально (при загрузке страницы) активной, включённой?

Tags: javascript, extjs

(1) В шапке сайта есть две кнопки отвечающие за смену языков.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно кнопку "RU", изначально сделать активной, изначально - при загрузке страницы. Активной, значит вот такой (2).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу это сделать? Я пытался принудительно ставить класс x-presses, принудительно запускать события, но всё это не работает.

Comment: >_< а как сделана эта кнопка? Если их рисует скрипт, то добавление класса можно бы добавить в конце этого скрипта... или просто задать кнопке какой-нибудь id="ru" и после их создания записать `document.getElementById('ru').click();`

Answer (score 0):

Задайте кнопке первоначальное состояние, например:

```
<button class="active"></button>
```

Tаким образом, кнопка при загрузке сайта будет иметь нужное состояние.
Все что остается сделать, логику для переключения языков.

В комментариях к моему ответу, Вы написали что у Вас переключает при нажатие на любую часть сайта, по этому написал небольший скрипт, который возможно поможет Вам решить проблему:

```js
  var languageOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.language-option');

  languageOptions.forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.addEventListener('click', switchLanguage);
  });

  function switchLanguage (event) {
    var targetElement = event.target;

    languageOptions.forEach(function(element, index) {
      element.classList.remove('active');
    });

    targetElement.classList.add('active');
  }
```

```css
html, body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

button.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <button id="ru" class="language-option active">RU</button>
  <button id="en" class="language-option">EN</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Данный способ решения проблемы я уже испытывал и его считаю костыльным, кроме того при клике пользователем в любой части сайта "active" у кнопки пропадает.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин совершенно с Вами не согласен, этот метод есть правильным, а то что у Вас пропадает `active` при клике на любую часть сайта, это результат неправильно решенной задачи, так сказать побочные эфекты.
Костыль - это при загрузке сайта, делать искуственный клик, вот это костыль.